# useState function passed down through props doesnt change value (In React-Router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-state

Here is my problem is that I need to change the value of the useState in parent component, from the child component(s). but the child components are Routes, so I passed them through like this;

```
const NurseInterface = () => {
const [wristbandID, setWristbandID] = useState(1);
...
<Switch>
                    <Route
                     exact path={`${path}/default-view`} 
                     render={(props)=> (
                         <NurseDefaultView {...props}  setWristbandID={setWristbandID}/>// Alternative way of Routing Components, allowing you to pass props to it 
                     )}
                    />
...
</Switch>
```

...
}

inside the Route is the NurseDefaultView which passes the state to Wristbands:

```
const NurseDefaultView = ({ setWristbandID }) => {
...
{wristbands ? <Wristbands wristbands={wristbands} setWristbandID={setWristbandID}/> : null}
}
```

and then Wristbands passes the state down to wristband cards through map()

```
    //React-Spring
  const transitions = useTransition(wristbands, wristband => wristband.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform:"translate(0px, -50px)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform:"translate(0px, 0px)" },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform:"translate(0px, -50px)" },
  })
  

    if (wristbands) {
    return (
      <>
         {transitions.map(({item, key, props})=> (
           item ? (
         <WristbandCard key={parseInt(item.id)}
            props={props}
            nurseView={true}
            setWristbandID={setWristbandID} 
            wristband={item}/> ) : null
          ))}
      </>
    )} else return <div>No Wristbands</div>
```

and WristbandCard looks this this:

```
const WristbandCard = ({ wristband, setWristbandID, setShowDetail, nurseView, props }) => {
  
 ...
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (nurseView) {
      console.log(wristband.id);
      setWristbandID(wristband.id);
    } else {
      console.log("SetShowDetail")
      setShowDetail(true);
      setWristbandID(wristband.id);
    }  
  }
  
  ...
     if (nurseView) return (
      <Link className="right" to={`patient-cart`}>
        <animated.article style={props} onClick={handleClick} className="card">
          <header>
            {battery(data)}
            <img alt="Wifi Icon by Google Inc (placeholder)" src={Connection}/>
          </header>
            <h1>{wristband.name}</h1>
            <div><img alt="transfer" src={Arrow}/><h3>{description(wristband, nurseView)}</h3></div>
          <footer><img alt="transfer" src={Transfer}/></footer>
        </animated.article>
      </Link>
    ); else return (
      <animated.figure style={props} onClick={handleClick} className={wristband.connected ? "card": "card red"}>
        <header>
          {battery(data)}
          <img alt="Wifi Icon by Google Inc (placeholder)" src={Wifi}/>
        </header>
        <h3>{description(wristband)}</h3>
        <h2>{wristband.name}</h2>
      </animated.figure>
    )
  }
```

but it doesnt work. And ive console logged the value of it set at the top level inside the Route, and the value. But in the parent, it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any examples of this working in react-router? I havent seen any sadly.

This makes me think that maybe Routes cant handle Hooks as props and I need to implement Redux for this, but i'm hoping that there is maybe somewhere I went wrong? because this is the only case where I need something like this.

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code where you're calling `setWristbandID` or we can't help you debug.

Comment: I apologise. Currently under a NDA right now so I have to be careful about what I post. But ive posted a reduced version of the code with the parts where I used setWristbandID. Do you mind having a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) with a [context hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to update a parent's state (wristband id) in a nested child component (setWristbandId).

Comment: Oh i see thats great, it looks kind of similar to Redux. So would you reccomend using this instead of trying to pass useState through props, when it comes to react-router? Thanks

Comment: You are prop drilling the setState down the chain of components and it might be easier to maintain and use.